# Solving for linear transformation matrix which makes $g(Im(f))\subset Im(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I did a problem giving me matrix A as
        \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & -1 \\
    3 & 1 & 2 \\
    2 & 3 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
and matrix B as
\begin{bmatrix}
    p & 0 & 5 \\
    0 & 5 & 5 \\
    7 & 0 & q \\
    \end{bmatrix}
and it asks me to do Linear Transformation : $f(x)=Ax$ and $g(x)=Bx$ , both $\mathbb{R}^3$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^3$

The problem asks me to find $p$ and $q$ which make $g(Im(f))\subset Im(f)$. Given that $g(Im(f))=\{g(x) | x\in Im(f)\}$

So, trying to solve this, First I find bases of $Im(f)$ which are 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    3\\
    2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
and 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    1\\
    3\\
    \end{bmatrix}

Then, I tried to get $g(Im(f))$ by doing $g(x)=Bx$ using linear combination of the bases of Image as $x$. Doing that I got,
\begin{bmatrix}
    a(p+10)+b(2p+15)\\
    a(25)+b(20)\\
    a(7+2q)+b(14+2q)\\
    \end{bmatrix}

And that needs to be the subset of $Im(f)$. I got struck here trying to solve for $p$ and $q$. How should I solving for them?

Answer (score 1):

First we need to check if basis of $Im(f)$, upon being mapped by $g$ still remains in $Im(f)$.

We want to ensure the existence of matrix $C$ such that $$B \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 1\\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} C$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} p & 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 5 & 5 \\ 7 & 0 & q\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 1\\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} C$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} p+10 & 2p+15\\ 25 & 20 \\ 7+2q & 14+3q\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 1\\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} C$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 1\\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} C = \begin{bmatrix} p+10 & 2p+15\\ 25 & 20 \\ 7+2q & 14+3q\end{bmatrix}  $$
Now, we perform row operations:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 & -5\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} C = \begin{bmatrix} p+10 & 2p+15\\ 25-3(p+10) & 20-3(2p+15) \\ 7+2q-2(p+10) & 14+3q-2(2p+15)\end{bmatrix}  $$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 & -1\\ 0 & -5\end{bmatrix} C = \begin{bmatrix} p+10 & 2p+15\\ 7+2q-2(p+10) & 14+3q-2(2p+15)\\ 25-3(p+10) & 20-3(2p+15) \end{bmatrix}  $$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 & -1\\ 0 & -5\end{bmatrix} C = \begin{bmatrix} p+10 & 2p+15\\ -13+2q-2p & -16+3q-4p\\ -5-3p & -25-6p \end{bmatrix}  $$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} C = \begin{bmatrix} p+10 & 2p+15\\ -13+2q-2p & -16+3q-4p\\ -5-3p-5(-13+2q-2p) & -25-6p-5(-16+3q-4p) \end{bmatrix}  $$

You would want the last row to be a zero row, you can now solve for $p$ and $q$.

Comment: I solved it by using last row = 0 (so, whatever C it is, it's 0) and get p = 10 and q =13. but I don't understand the last part that you state about 2 independent?

Comment: oops, the independent part was a typo